# Read file from position

Tags: c#, file-io

```
FileStream infile = new FileStream(@"C:\Users\John\Desktop\ProjectNew\nov.txt",     FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
        int position = x.Length;
        infile.Seek(position, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

But Seek method returns number. How to read the file 'infile' from position to end in a string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is this what you're after? Assuming you wanted to start reading from position 100...

```
       using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            fs.Seek(100, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            byte[] b = new byte[fs.Length - 100];
            fs.Read(b, 0, (int)(fs.Length - 100));

            string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The [Seek](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek.aspx) method is supposed to return a number, the new position in the stream. Now just call whatever [Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.read.aspx) function you want.

Comment: But Read function returns int.

Comment: I don't need the number of bytes. I need to get a string variable which will contain the value of the file from the position to the end.

Comment: Okay, so keep reading the file until you reach the end and put the data you read in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Seek() only places the *file pointer* somewhere else. If you do a read before the seek, it will read from the beginning of the file. If you read after the seek, it will start reading from *position*.

So to read the file from position to the end, do `Seek()`, followed by `Read()` or `ReadToEnd()`.

Comment: But they both return numbers.