# How can I compare files excluding the file header?

Tags: c#, windows, file, io, header

I know I can MD5 a complete file, this is **not** what I want to do.

I want to get the header and the actual file content.

I know each file has a header and then has the content. I want to compare the actual content of two files to determine if the content is the same and for this I will then use simple md5 on the content.

My issue is how do I separate out the headers from the content so I can do the calculation ? - to make this more clear the offsets is what I will need to know ; will they be the same for all files or different and if different how can I find the details so I can accomplish this . ( I know about gargling but can't find it).

```
using (var md5 = MD5.Create())
{
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        return md5.ComputeHash(SplitContentFromHeader(stream));
    }
}


SplitContentFromHeader(stream)
{
.. do the thing and return the shortened stream 
}
```

Comment: Many types of file don't have a header at all.  For those that do, there is no way to distinguish the header from the content without knowing what type of file it is.  And in most cases, the header matters and should be included in the comparison anyway.

Comment: @Harry Johnston , for any given file that has a header why would you say it should be included, I mean for example an image file - the image itself is what makes it the same is that not correct? Am I not thinking correctly  that the headers defines certain meta data but the actual contents(for example text of a document)  If the text is the same, the file content is really the same?

Comment: It depends on the format. Consider, for example, an executable file. The header includes the starting address (and other critical information) so two executable files that are identical apart from the header could behave completely differently. The same is true of the older Microsoft Office format; you could put two unrelated documents into one file, and the headers would determine which one you read. I imagine you could break a GIF file by changing the version number in the header; you could definitely break a ZIP file (including modern Microsoft Office files) by changing header information.

Comment: ... and so on.  If you want to do a "smart" comparison, i.e., only ignoring metadata such as timestamps, you really do have to know exactly how each specific file format works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `.Seek` and `.Read` methods. See documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx and here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read(v=vs.110).aspx

Copied from a similar question here [Read file from position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596302/read-file-from-position) try something like this:

```
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"file.txt", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        fs.Seek(100, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        byte[] b = new byte[fs.Length - 100];
        fs.Read(b, 0, (int)(fs.Length - 100));

        string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(b);
    }
```

Comment: I do appreciate your answer but how to read from an offset is not what I am looking for - as I need to know the offset to start from. I have been searching online for file byte structure headers and offsets. I know that the files have a header for the file system, and I am not sure if there is an additional header (Jpeg I know has its own header) how can I know the offsets so that I can split header from actual content; filestream to byte[] would get the array, then I just need to know where to split it. So I have two parts Header, Content. I will edit my question to clarify.